# Why does the following code lead to Timeout?

Tags: javascript, timeout, runtime-error

I came across this issue in the problem titled: [Another Prime Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/acm-vit-cpp/challenges/another-prime-problem/problem).Here's my solution which passed test case-1, but for other test cases it led to Runtime error(Terminated due to timeout).

```js
    function processData(input) {
       input=input.split('\n');
       input.shift();
       for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
          values(input[i]);
       }
    } 
    function values(num){
       var sum=0;
       num=num.split(' ');
       for(var i=num[0];i<=num[1];i++){
           for(var j=2;j<=i;j++){
               if(i%j==0 && isprime(j)){
                   sum+=j;
               }
           }
       }
       console.log(sum)
    }
    function isprime(val){
       let flag=1;
       for(var i=2;i<val;i++){
            if(val%i==0){
               flag=0;
            }
       }
       if(flag==1){
          return true;
       }
       else{
           return false;
       }
    }
```

What's the issue in this code that leads to timeout?

More details:

Input Format:
The first line contains T denoting the total number of testcases.
First line of each testcase contains two integers X and Y.

Constraints:

1 ≤ T ≤ 10000

2 ≤ X ≤ Y ≤ 10^5

Output Format:
Sum of prime factors of each number in the range [X, Y].

Comment: i guess you should visit this page here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/